# Проверки на основном сайте?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, очередь-проверок

На странице очередей проверок основного сайта идёт пункт

> Проверки на Мете

А куда с меты делась аналогичная ссылка для основного сайта?

[image: скриншот с основного сайта]

[image: скриншот с меты]

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я помню, её никогда и не было. Было только некоторое удивление и немного разочарования по поводу отсутствия.

Поддержать имеющееся предложение можно на MSE: [Add a link from Meta /review to its main /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251265/339911). Правда, не знаю, сколько надо собрать голосов, чтобы на него обратили внимание разработчики.

Comment: Странно.. Мне казалось, что была... В любом случае, почему бы не добавить?

Comment: @Qwertiy для симметричности было бы разумно, да. Можно проголосовать [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251265/339911).

Comment: ‏‏Г‏‏о‏‏т‏‏о‏‏в‏‏о‏‏!‏‏

Comment: @Qwertiy о5 этот, ломающий форматирование приложения, комментарий :)

Comment: Значит не пофиксили ^_^

Comment: @Qwertiy в андроиде вообще вряд ли скоро пофиксят. В iOS, я думаю, запилят в ближайших апдейтах. Хотя, могу ошибаться.